# Get a table data from database using WebApi & Entity Framework 6.XX

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

i made a Entity Data Model From Database Table Like this. [image]

Then add 4 line of codes in WebApiConfig.cs to get json data from response.

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Then i created a Controller (Web API 2 controller with read/Write action) named importController.

then i added this codes to add and  retrieve data from database. but not working.

```
    CodeXenETSEntities db = new CodeXenETSEntities();  

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("pushlocation")]
    // POST: api/pushlocation  
    public HttpResponseMessage pushlocation( int userid,decimal longitude, decimal latitude , TimeSpan time )
    {
        user_locations ulog = new user_locations();
        ulog.user_id = userid;
        ulog.lon = longitude;
        ulog.lat = latitude;
        ulog.time = time;
        db.user_locations.Add(ulog);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "Successfully Created");
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("pulllocation")]
    // GET: api/pulllocation/5  
    public HttpResponseMessage pulllocation(int userid, decimal longitude, decimal latitude, TimeSpan time)
    {

        db.user_locations.ToList();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, "Success");
    }
```

**this is the output :**
[image]

**Database Data :**

[image]

Comment: I believe your url should be something along the lines of http://localhost:57715/api/import/pulllocation/

Comment: Also, your route config in `WebApiConfig.cs` may not allow for parameterless calls since you have specified four parameters in your `pulllocation` method

Comment: @AndyArndt thanks for the suggestion. but still not working. any other idea or suggestion ?

Comment: @sly  what to do then? please advice me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things:

**1)** In `WebApiConfig.cs` use `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

**2)** In `importController` change `public HttpResponseMessage pulllocation(int userid, decimal longitude, decimal latitude, TimeSpan time)` **to** `public HttpResponseMessage pulllocation()`

**3)** In Browser address bar use `http://localhost:57715/api/{controller name}/pulllocation`. in your case `http://localhost:57715/api/import/pulllocation`

I hope this will solve

Comment: Thanks Man. you saved me :D